# Excel Formula, Sumifs, condition is an array range

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, sumifs

**Goal**: Use SUMIFS to get the sum of value if color is Red or Yellow. Outcome should be 3.

```
+---+--------+-------+---+-----------+
|   |   A    |   B   | C |     D     |
+---+--------+-------+---+-----------+
| 1 | Key    | Value |   | Condition |
| 2 | Red    | 1     |   | Red       |
| 3 | Yellow | 2     |   | Yellow    |
| 4 | Green  | 3     |   |           |
+---+--------+-------+---+-----------+
```

**Problem**:

- It works if I hardcode the condition {"Red","Yellow"}. The result is 3.

  `=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B4, A2:A4, {"Red","Yellow"}))`
- But if I reference the condition by cell D2:D3, I get 0.

  `=SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B4, A2:A4, D2:D3))`

**Question:** How do I reference the condition dynamically by cell and make it work?

Comment: Instead of Enter when exiting edit mode use Ctrl-Shift-Enter, or instead of SUM use SUMPRODUCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT() instead of SUM():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B2:B4,A2:A4,D2:D3))
```

[image]

---

One note:

This variation allows the expansion of the lists without the need to reapply the ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",D:D))))
```

[image]

Comment: Feel free to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Yep, checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `SUMIF()` together:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A4,"Red",B2:B4)+SUMIF(A2:A4,"Yellow",B2:B4)
```

Or make sure you're using <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> with your current formula attempt.